# How to choose which python executable to run when using venv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

I have a python installation on my pc (windows 10) which comes from Anaconda. I am a data scientist and using conda as a package manager is very convenient for me.

However, sometimes I want to develop a small app or script to share with my colleagues. In these cases I create a project folder and `python -m venv .venv` inside it.
This way, I can install only the essential packages I need, and later share the requirements.txt file.

The issue I'm having, is that the python interpreter being used is still the default one, namely, the one that came with Anaconda, **even if I activate the virtual environment and deactivate the conda one**.

Specifically, if I run python in the terminal, I get this warning message:

```
Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation
```

This is rather inconvenient. My base python installation is 3.7, but if I wanted to use an earlier version, or 3.8, I can't seem to be able to choose.

I would expect that the python executable being used is the one in the current active environment, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

How can I obtain that?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive you are running the activation script from the `venv` folder you want to use? Do you get that "environment not activated" message in even while your environment is activated in that current terminal window? You will know if it's activated because you should see your environment name appear at the beginning of the terminal prompt

Comment: yeah, 100% positive. If I don't "conda deactivate", the error message is not present.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to install the version of python you want to use in your venv. It must already be available somewhere on your system to create a venv using it.

Then instead of just `python -m venv .venv` you specify which python with the full path : `/path/to/pythonX.Y -m venv .venv`

You can't have a venv that shares multiple versions of python, to my knowledge at least.

Comment: Cool, I had no idea about that. I also believe that I'm getting this error because I have Anaconda in my PATH env variable, and did "conda init" in my terminal, so for some reason it thinks that the interpreter that is in my venv belongs to a conda environment, even if it doesn't.

Comment: I admit that I never used conda, but quickly reading the doc, I think you can indeed manage multiple python versions but not in the same venv. I understand that conda itself uses a specific python version, but once `init` you can create envs with different versions with `conda create --name xxxx python=X.Y`

Comment: Yes, i know about that. The thing about conda is that it is a package manager meant for data sciency tasks. So when a new env is created with `conda create`, it also installs some packages by default. This is ok for most cases, but if I need to share an app with someone, all those extra packages that are not needed are just bloating the requirements.txt file, hence why I use python venv and pip in these cases, as they only install exactly what you ask them too and keep the env as clean as possible.